# How to call multiple backing bean methods in JSF 1.2?

Tags: jsf, call, javabeans

Is there a way to call multiple methods from backing bean in JSF?

I have something like this:

```
                <h:outputLink value="#{bean.selectedEntry.link}">
                    <h:graphicImage
                        url="/CMS/button.png"
                        alt="button"></h:graphicImage>
            </h:outputLink>
```

I want to execute some other method from Bean when user click on outputLink. It is possible?

P.S I'm using JSF 1.2

Comment: Why dont you use actionListener , like <h:outputLink value="#{bean.selectedEntry.link}" actionListener="#{bean.someMethod}"> public void someMethod(ActionEvent event){}

Comment: @Daniel: This attribute isn't available in outputlink.

Comment: my bad... thought it was commandlink... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it by `<h:commandLink>`.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{bean.openLink}">
        <h:graphicImage
            url="/CMS/button.png"
            alt="button"></h:graphicImage>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void openLink() throws IOException {
    // You can just call any (multiple) Java methods here the usual way.
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(selectedEntry.getLink());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to call that method from method you are calling in bean?

If the method you are calling is used in other scenarios, then refactor your code to separate concerns and provide entry point for every different scenario.